# Why isn’t “It’s” a complete sentence, but “It is” is?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, contractions, ellipses, contraction-vs-full-form

I’m a native English speaker, so I understand that

> It’s.

is not a complete sentence, whereas the sentence

> It is.

is a complete sentence.

What linguistic mechanism prevents “It’s.” from being a complete sentence in English?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question. I can think of an explanation, but there might be others.

The first is that in the uncontracted version, you'll notice that when you say *It is*, *is* bears the stress: in a more emphatic form the vowel in *is* will be lengthened, and the pitch of your voice will modulate from high to low. Those cues are used by your listener to understand that you are stressing *is* to place contrastive focus on the truth value of some proposition that's been called into question (sometimes called verum focus). I can't think of any other context where you'd say *It is.*

However, when you contract *it is* to *it's*, the whole point of the contraction is to convert a two syllable iamb into one atonic syllable, so that you can speak faster, or to avoid a stress clash, but it makes no sense to do so when you need to preserve the usual stress pattern of *it is*.

Notice that you can say *It's not* (also used for verum focus) just fine, because the stress is supposed to belong to *not* anyways.